# Which GUI framework is used to make Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gui, c++, c

I'm interested to know, Which GUI framework is used to build ubuntu? As well i know it is built in `C/C++`. But what GUI is used to make Ubuntu?

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Since 11.04, Ubuntu has used the Unity graphical shell. According to [the Wikipedia entry on Unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(user_interface)), the current version uses the QML framework, which is part of the Qt project.

Comment: You mean.. It is purely built in `QT Framework`?

Comment: @lololo - No.  He means what he said.

Comment: @lololo From what I can tell, QML is a separate framework from Qt, even though they're part of the same project.